# Can't see red underlines for errors for Java on VS code

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code

I updated to the latest version of VS code and I can no longer get red underlines for my errors, it just tells me errors once I've compiled the code which is super annoying. I am using a mac silicon.

I have tried downgrading VS code back to `1.77.3` however I am still having the same problem. Have installed and uninstalled Java extension.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a complete [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) without uninstallation of it. Use the following command to clear the language server cache.

```
Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace
```

[image]

In addition, check or delete your personal [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), one of these settings may cause error.